# C# Reflection.Emit external c++ dll throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, reflection.emit

I tried to generate assembly which calls dll library, but stumbled from unresolvable error.
I have compiled sll.dll written in c++ (only one class - StackInt) and compiled with parameters CLR x86 Release.

```
#pragma once
// sll.dll
using namespace System;
namespace SLCollections {
    public ref class StackInt
    {
    private:
        array< Int32 >^ data;
        Int32 size, capacity;
        void grow() {
            array< Int32 >^ newdata = gcnew array< Int32 >(capacity << 1);
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                newdata[i] = data[i];
            }
            capacity <<= 1;
            data = newdata;
        }
    public:
        StackInt() : size(0), capacity(2), data(gcnew array< Int32 >(2)) {}
        void push(Int32 item) {
            if (capacity >= size) {
                grow();
            }
            data[size++] = item;
        }
        Int32 pop() {
            return data[--size];
        }
        Int32 top() {
            return data[size - 1];
        }
        bool isEmpty() {
            return size == 0;
        }
    };
}
```

I want to use this library in dynamically generated assembly written in C# using Reflection Emit and compiled with x86 Release configuration options. C# code uses sll.dll (referenced dll):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using SLCollections;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Generator
{
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string moduleName = "test.exe";
        try
        {
            // worked code!
            //StackInt stack = new StackInt();
            //stack.push(10);

            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(moduleName));
            AssemblyBuilder asmb = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            ModuleBuilder modb = asmb.DefineDynamicModule(moduleName);
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modb.DefineType("Foo");
            MethodBuilder methb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main",
                MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), 
                Type.EmptyTypes);

            ILGenerator il = methb.GetILGenerator();
            Type stackType = typeof(StackInt);
            LocalBuilder localStackBuilder = il.DeclareLocal(stackType);
            Type[] t = new Type[0];

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
               stackType.GetConstructor(t));

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, localStackBuilder);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, localStackBuilder);

            MethodInfo pushMethod = stackType.GetMethod(
                "push", new Type[] { typeof(int) });

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, pushMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

            // return
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            typeBuilder.CreateType();
            modb.CreateGlobalFunctions();
            asmb.SetEntryPoint(methb);
            asmb.Save(moduleName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It is possible to create  object of class StackInt which included in sll.dll and call it's methods with `using SLCollections` directive. When I compile and save assembly all is fine. However, assembly test.exe starts with an error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled Message: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' 
occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information:
Failed to load file or assembly 
"SLL, Version=1.0.6354.41871, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
or one of their dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program that has an incorrect format.
```

Disassembled code from generated assembly is fine.

Where I have mistaken?

Comment: BadImageFormat exception usually (in my experience) comes from two main reasons : 

 1. x86 vs x64 : if your .Net assembly is x86, you can't load an x64 dll
 2. .Net Framework versions: from a .Net 2.0 assembly, you can't load a .Net 4.5 dll.

Comment: Actually, I have seen posts with the same problems and check different conf options, but my configurations are identical for both .dll and .exe called the library (x86 and .Net v 4.5.2). Both were compiled on the same machine.